# How can I write a loop in fortran that reads line by line until a line is empty

Tags: loops, input, command-line, fortran, eof

[Fortran95 question: The input is two integers in every line as shown in the pic below. Reading from command line how can I keep reading line by line until a line is empty. The number of lines is known.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iMVJ.png)

The code I have right now:

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer :: n, a
    do
        read *, n, a
        print *, n, a
    end do
end program main
```

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Instead post code as plain text, formatted as "code".

Comment: Did you mean *The number of lines is **not** known.*?

Comment: Do you actually mean: "How to stop when the line is empty, in other words, *at the end of the file*?". That has been treated in many questions and answers here.

Comment: Please feel welcome here, I suggest taking the [tour] and reading [ask]. Your question will likely be closed as a duplicate of some other question. Please do not take it personally, the answers in the duplicate should directly help you.

Comment: I will also write the gist here. You can use `iostat=` specifier in the `read` statement to set an integer flag that will be nonzero when an error condition or an end-of-file or end-of-record condition happened. You can also use the `end=` specifier to set the label to which the program jumps if an end-of-file condition happened.